# difference of uv mapping between viewpoint and render

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor

[image]

In the view point, roof's pattern is straight line.[image]

but in the render, roof's pattern is diagonal line. why this problem happen?

Comment: There is Random socket output added to the UV map vectors. On the other hand Texture shading mode shows only mapping of the currently selected texture without taking into account any nodes. So likely end result is the difference between your node setup and texture mapping.

Comment: Not using Math node but using MixRGB node can solve that problem.